# Ionic Pro build fails, ionic deploy manifest failed

Tags: ionic3

I'm trying to use Ionic Pro and don't understand why but when I try to build it it says 
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/usr/src/app/www 
ionic deploy manifest failed`

This doesn't happen when using `ionic serve`.

This is my `ionic info output`

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node  : v8.11.3
npm   : 5.6.0 
OS    : macOS High Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 9.4 Build version 9F1027a
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just figured out why... The www folder was ignored by git.

Just add it by force (`git add -f www`)

Comment: I wanted to add that anyone arriving here when trying to deploy an app using AppFlow: I was getting this error in the build pipeline because I also had `www/` added to my `.gitignore`. removing it fixed the error.